# Edit mode rendering modifiers and causing problems in visualizing

Tags: rendering, edit-mode

I've been following Blender Guru's chair tutorial for a while. Part of the chair has subdivision modifier on it. When I go to Edit mode the subdivision modifier is still shown (now like in his video) which makes the edges and faces a little bit harder to visualize for me.

This is how it looks like in his YouTube video. (and I expect like this)
[image: Expected one]

While in my one it shows up like this (I am also in Edit mode)
[image]

You can see I cannot clearly visualize and select the edges required to select. So what can I do?

My Blender version: 3.0.0
Date: December 2, 2021
Branch: Master

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just turn off the "Display modifier in edit mode" option, the one highlighted in green

[image: an image of the modifier]